# Why do some states in India have a unicameral legislature and some have a Bicameral one?

Tags: india, state-legislatures, legislature

I recently learnt that some states in India have a [Bicameral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicameralism) legislature whereas some others have  a [Unicameral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicameralism) legislature. Why is this so?

FYI: The [Parliament of India](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament_of_India) (at the national level) follows a Bicameral system of legislature.

Comment: Don't know about India in particular, but this sort of thing is not unheard of internationally. See for example Nebraska (US) and Queensland (AU).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constitution of each state in India is determined by the state (within some boundaries). There are some advantages to a unicameral system (simpler, cheaper, less bureaucracy) and some disadvantages (less effective scrutiny, only one system of representation). It has been a matter of the state to decide whether the advantages outweigh the disadvantages. Ultimately this is a matter of judgement.